# Cannot replace string + int in android

Tags: android, replace

I cannot replace string by `String str = str.replace();` What is wrong in my code?

```
String str = "NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 NUM4 NUM5";
    String t ="";

    String[] arrStr = {"N", "U", "M"};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
            t = str.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);
        }

    }
System.out.println(t);
```

always t = "NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 NUM4 NUM5"; it not change because `str.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);` not replace.
I dont recieve any error in logcat

UPDATE FULL CODE:

```
public String createChemistry(String a) {
    String t = "";
    String[] arrStr = {
            "H", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca",
            "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Br", "Xe", "Rn", "I", "Sn", "In", "Cd",
            "Rb", "Sr", "Pb", "Ag", "Cd", "Ba", "Au", "Hg", "Pb", "Cs"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
            t = a.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);
        }

    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error/exception? please put your log that you are printing in logcat.

Comment: what is "a.replace"  wher is a???? and where is t???????

Comment: @SilvansSolanki not any error in logcat, only cannot replace.

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N sr I updated my code

Comment: check the answer i posted and tell me did i understood correctly or not

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N sr,it not correctly

Comment: only you want to change M then why you created N , U, M ??? logic is wrong....

Comment: do you want to replace N = N_ , U= U_ , M=M_ ????

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N I know how to replace  replace("M","M_1"). Because my is code too long to post here so, I create example to post

Comment: then please explain clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
public String createChemistry(String a) {
    String t = a;
    String[] arrStr = {
        "H", "Li", "Be", "B", "C", "N", "O", "F", "Ne", "Na", "Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "S", "Cl", "Ar", "K", "Ca",
        "Cr", "Mn", "Fe", "Co", "Ni", "Cu", "Zn", "Br", "Xe", "Rn", "I", "Sn", "In", "Cd",
        "Rb", "Sr", "Pb", "Ag", "Cd", "Ba", "Au", "Hg", "Pb", "Cs"
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
            t = t.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);
        }
    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: 1. `String t = a;` not `""`
2. `t = t.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);` not `t = a.replace...`

Comment: Replace doesn't change the string on which is called, but only returns the result. That's why you must call `t = t.replace...` so that past changes don't get lost (i.e. in your code only `Cs9` will get transformed to `Cs_9` since all the other changes are ignored).

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want to replace only M i have an simple replace solution here

```
String str = "NUM1 NUM2 NUM3 NUM4 NUM5";
System.out.println(str.replace("M","M_"));

//OUTPUT
NUM_1 NUM_2 NUM_3 NUM_4 NUM_5
```

If you want something else tell me i will edit the answer.

Comment: No, I want something else,  this is my example for my code. I'm wondering why I can not replace "replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k)"

Answer (score 0):

Your `t` is changes every time, may be you want to concatenate result?

```
t += str.replace(arrStr[i] + k, arrStr[i] + "_" + k);
```

Comment: No, i want to System.out.println(t);, alway t = "NUM1 NUM2 NUM3  NUM4 NUM5" It not change because it not replace but I cannot why?